# SSIS adding XML to a fixed width flat file

Tags: ssis, fixed-width

I have a package that looks for new files and parses them into their respective tables. Since the filenames include a date, I have to search for a specific string that identifies the file instead of using a static filename. Everything works, except for that using this dynamic method of finding the file seems to be adding a ton of XML formatting to the file, which is then being inserted as records into the database. When I point the flat file connection manager at file directly using it's name, this problem does not happen. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you explain "using this dynamic method of finding the file seems to be adding a ton of XML formatting to the file, which is then being inserted as records into the database"? I *think* the first half is stating that adding expressions and such makes the .dtsx file bigger but that should be unrelated to the size of data processed by the package itself

Comment: @billinkc , I meant that using wildcards to find a string in the filename is what is causing the problem. When I use a static filepath to specify a file, the extra junk is not added to the data.